# Add values in rows if first values in consecutive rows match python

Tags: python, dataframe

I am working to reduce the rows in my dataframe based on the values in the first rows. If the value in the first column of a row matches the value in the second row of the first, I want to add the data in the residual columns.

My dataframe looks like this:

| position | length | height |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5.5 | 0.0 |
| 1 | 0.0 | 2.1 |
| 2 | 4.1 | 0.0 |
| 2 | 0.0 | 3.5 |

My desired output is this:

| position | length | height |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5.5 | 2.1 |
| 2 | 4.1 | 3.5 |

Answer (score 0):

Try `.groupby` + `.sum()`:

```py
x = df.groupby("position", as_index=False).sum()
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
   position  length  height
0         1     5.5     2.1
1         2     4.1     3.5
```